# Can we return Json formatted data from Web Service provider Function in Lotus

Tags: json, web-services, web, lotus

I am new to Lotus Web Service. I have created a Web service provider which has two function in it. EmployeeProfile and EmployeeLogin. Both the function have certain paramter to process the function logic. I want to return the JSON formatted data from these two function. Is there a way to achieve this in Lotus 8.5 or Lotus 9.0.

Any help will be of great help.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Lotus Web Services :-)

First, the built-in webservices are all SOAP-based! They are from a time where JSON based services were not that well-known.

So if you want JSON based (REST) services I suggest you take a look at DAS (Domino Access Services), specifically DDS (Domino Data Services). These are standard services coming out of the box. Should these not serve your needs you can easily build your own (using either LotusScript in agents - or better Java). How to do that is too big a subject for an answer here - but I can point you in the direction of an introduction to RESTful services: http://www.slideshare.net/JohnDalsgaard/dannotes-19-20-november-2014?qid=37e47470-8225-4582-9189-3dbe5f6be690&v=default&b=&from_search=2

If you go to EngageUG in Belgium next week then you will see the updated version of that :-)

/John

Comment: Thanks John. I used the xpages approach to display JSON using java.

Comment: Great. If this answer helped you then you should mark it - to help other easily find solutions to similar questions ;-)